# Programmatically set listbox selected items from comma separated list

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm having issues with setting selected items in a listbox from a comma separated data list.

The comma delimited list has values like this (valueList): `A,B,C,D`

```
List<string> values = valueList.Split(',').ToList();

foreach(string val in values)
{
    listBox.SelectedItems.Add(val);
}
```

Basically I loop through the items in the delimited list and attempt to set the selected items in the listbox (which contains the items `A, B, C, D, E, F`). With this code, I suspected it would select items `A-D` in the list box, but it doesn't highlight/select any items.

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of application you are targeting ? WinForms?

Comment: @Habib Yes, it's a WinForms application.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing like `listBox.Items.Add(val);` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have already have items in your `ListBox` and on you want to select only those returned by the `string.Split` operation then use [ListBox.SetSelected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected(v=vs.110).aspx) method like:

```
var valueArray = valueList.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < listBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (valueArray.Contains(listBox.Items[i].ToString()))
    {
        listBox.SetSelected(i, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of "SelectedItems", use "Items".Use something like below:

```
string a = "1,2,3,4";
    List<string> values = a.Split(',').ToList();
    ListBox lb = new ListBox();
    foreach (string val in values)
    {
        lb.Items.Add(val.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that the items are already in the list?

From the [ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection Class documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedobjectcollection(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection class stores the selected items in the ListBox. The items stored in the ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection are items contained within the ListBox.ObjectCollection class.

Other folks have given you the code that will work, but I'm going to go ahead an post this because I think it is worth reading through the remarks in the documentation to understand the relationship between the items in the Items collection and the items in the SelectedItems collection - it might help with the next step after you get those items selected.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
foreach (string val in values)
   listBox.SelectedItems.Add(listBox.Items[listBox.Items.IndexOf(val)]);
```

but may raise an exception if val wasn't found within the listBox.Items